# c# Automatic colorcycle for legends in MS Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, colors, mschart

I'm loading dataseries into a MS Chart and would like to set the legend/series colors automatically instead of having to choose manually..
Does anyone know of a good way to do that, so colors that are too close doesnt get chosen for the same chart?
Thanks!

Comment: if not duplicate then it has a usable answer..
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for palettes? This code is straight out of the chart samples (http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/mschart) for palettes:

```
// Standard palette
chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.BrightPastel;
// Use a custom palette
Color[] colorSet = new Color[4] { Color.Red, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Purple };
chart2.PaletteCustomColors = colorSet;
chart2.Palette = ChartColorPalette.None;
```

Comment: thanks i was looking for something like this :)

Comment: Happy to help. If it answers the question it is customary to accept the answer.